# su Authentication failure

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, useradd

```
OS Ubuntu 18.04
```

I am trying to add a user, with password, home directory, create a group with the same name, using a bash script.

I tried:

```
sudo useradd -U -m -p $(openssl passwd -1 'some_password') test
```

The user was created, here's the entry from /etc/passwd:

```
test:x:1004:1004::/home/test:/bin/sh
```

The home directory was created:

```
/home/test
```

and the group was created.

The problem, is that when I try doing:

```
su test
```

It asks me for a password, but when I enter the password, I get the following error:

```
su: Authentication failure
```

PS: I realize the dangers of adding passwords to bash scripts, but this is not what I am doing. The script asks the user to enter the password, and uses it in the script like this:

```
sudo useradd -U -m -p $(openssl passwd -1 '$password') $username
```

Any ideas?

On the same system, I tried using useradd, to add a test2 user, and entered the password. I was able to su with test2

For diagnostics purposes, I created a bash script doit.sh and had in it:

```
passwd='SomePassword1234'
username='test2'
sudo useradd -U -m -p $(openssl passwd -1 '$password') $username
```

I ran it as:

```
bash -x doit.sh
```

Here's the output:

```
ubuntu@myserver:~$ bash -x doit.sh
+ passwd=SomePassword1234
+ username=test2
++ openssl passwd -1 '$password'
+ sudo useradd -U -m -p '$1$okAtvbfD$hVwD0AoMWR5AiTw.9Bztf.' test2
```

and I try to su:

```
ubuntu@myserver:~$ su test2
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
ubuntu@myserver:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the quoting, '$password' will be literally that: `$password` and not the value of the $password variable. `"$password"` is required here.

```
sudo useradd -U -m -p $(openssl passwd -1 "$password") $username
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It thinks "$passwd" is an empty string: ++ openssl passwd -1 ''